# PHP Notice: Undefined index: content

Tags: php, arrays

I know this question sounds silly, and seems like a duplicate to the other questions, but I can almost assure you it is not a duplicate.

I am getting an issue from PHP: 
 Notice: Undefined index: content in FILE_PATH on line 21

Line 21: `echo htmlentities($about['content']);`

I know for sure that `$about['content']` is set because for debugging, I have

```
print_r($about)
```

Which gives me

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [page] => About Us
            [content] => I have stuff here.... content for test purpose.
        )

)
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

**Edit**
This question is not duplicate because all the answers to the other questions don't talk about array of array. Please do not mark this question as duplicate.

Comment: Array of Array, try `$about[0]['content']`

Comment: @pce That's right. Thanks for the comment. It worked!

Comment: @RiggsFolly You right. That's why I needed clarification. I missed how I had to arrays, I can't figure out why but it works anyways.

Comment: @RiggsFolly While I too agree closing it but the OP needed clarification. So technically this is not a duplicate.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Ok, no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your `print_r` looks like you need to correct the source, or use:

```
echo htmlentities($about[0]['content']);
```

The `$about` is an array of array that contains the `content` index. One of the solution is to use:

```
$about = $about[0]; // Only if you know that this is the only case.
```

The right way is to correct at the source, why it is not being a source array, but has another sub-array.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have no idea why it's an array of array. Thanks again

Comment: @Dev You are welcome... Just go through the code.